# Hibernate creates SELECT query for each lazy loaded element in @ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, quarkus-panache

I'm working on a PostgreSQL table USERS with 50k entries. A USER can have one or more GROUPs. These two tables are joined using a joining table USER_GROUP (with user_id and group_id). The relationship is defined as:

```
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="user_group",
            joinColumns={
                    @JoinColumn(name="user_uid", referencedColumnName="user_uid")},
            inverseJoinColumns={
                    @JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="group_id")})
    private Set<GroupEntity> groups = new HashSet<>();
```

On the real database, very few users have an assigned group. In one use-case, I need to query all users and their respective groups. The group name needs to be stored in a String. I load the groups with :

```
String groups = userList.add(String.join(",", user.getGroups().stream().map(Group::getName)                                                                  .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

This query is extremely slow, as Hibernate creates a select query for each User. Is there any way to speed things up? Am I missing something?

My alternative approach would be to create a database view:

```
CREATE VIEW user_view AS SELECT user.user_id, group_names from user left outer join (select user_id, string_agg(group_name, ',') group_names from user_group natural left join group GROUP BY user_id) AS g ON user.user_id = g.user_id;
```

Is there a way to do this efficiently with Hibernate? I'm using Quarkus and Panache, but there is some Criteria code in place as well.

I hope my example is easy to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it's pretty simple actually. You can use a join fetch in your HQL query:

```
select u from UserEntity u join fetch u.groups
```

This way, Hibernate will join and fetch along all the collection elements as part of a single query.
Other possible alternatives are to use an entity graph, or a specialized HQL query e.g.

```
select u.id, string_agg(g.name, ",") from UserEntity u join u.groups g group by u.id
```

That last query will select the user id and the comma separated list as string.